# how to define ACL rules to control properties of resource

Tags: hyperledger-composer

the documentation suggest ACL can control access to a property in resource:

[" Simple rules are used to control access to a namespace, asset or property of an asset"](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/acl_language.html)

but I can't find any info on how to define ACL rules to control a property of resource. would appreicate if anyone can advise or point me to documentations. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Property level access control has not yet been implemented and is hence not yet supported.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of this, if you read further into that the [ACL Documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/acl_language.html) you can see that you when a participant tries to access an asset, the rules can check the properties of the asset to determine whether or not that participant is the owner of that asset.

Quoted from the documentation:

> The rule below states that any instance of the `org.example.SampleParticipant` type can perform ALL operations on all instances of `org.example.SampleAsset` IF the participant is the owner of the asset.

```
rule SampleConditionalRule {
  description: "Description of the ACL rule"
  participant(m): "org.example.SampleParticipant"
  operation: ALL
  resource(v): "org.example.SampleAsset"
  condition: (v.owner.getIdentifier() == m.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW
}
```

> The rule below states that any instance of the org.example.SampleParticipant type can perform ALL operations on all instances of `org.example.SampleAsset` IF the participant is the owner of the asset AND the participant submitted a transaction of the org.example.SampleTransaction type to perform the operation.

```
rule SampleConditionalRuleWithTransaction {
  description: "Description of the ACL rule"
  participant(m): "org.example.SampleParticipant"
  operation: READ, CREATE, UPDATE
  resource(v): "org.example.SampleAsset"
  transaction(tx): "org.example.SampleTransaction"
  condition: (v.owner.getIdentifier() == m.getIdentifier())
  action: ALLOW
}
```